# Fatal error on makefile, need to understand the problem

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile is giving the following error messages:

```
ma.c:(.text+0x5aa): multiple definition of `dividetoken'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/src/ma.o: In function `main':
ma.c:(.text+0x629): multiple definition of `main'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x6ef): first defined here
obj/src/cv.o: In function `readln':
cv.c:(.text+0xb2): multiple definition of `readln'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x7f): first defined here
obj/src/cv.o: In function `dividetoken':
cv.c:(.text+0x176): multiple definition of `dividetoken'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/src/cv.o: In function `main':
cv.c:(.text+0x1f5): multiple definition of `main'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x6ef): first defined here
obj/src/sv.o: In function `readln':
sv.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `readln'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x7f): first defined here
obj/src/sv.o: In function `dividetoken':
sv.c:(.text+0x150): multiple definition of `dividetoken'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/src/sv.o: In function `main':
sv.c:(.text+0xcb5): multiple definition of `main'
obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x6ef): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:17: recipe for target 'program' failed
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

What should I do ? Can it be easily solved ? I don't know what to do

My makefile looks like this:

```
ODIR = obj
IDIR = include
SDIR = src

CC = gcc
EXE = program

DEPS = $(IDIR)/$(wildcard*.h)
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c)

OBJECTS = $(foreach o, $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES)), $(ODIR)/$o)

$(ODIR)/%.o : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< 

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXE)

clean:
    rm $(ODIR)/$(SDIR)/*
    rm $(EXE)
```

I hope this can help to see what my mistake was.

Comment: What does your Makefile look like? What command was it running when it produced these errors? The problem is very simple, but without seeing what you're doing, it is difficult to offer a specific solution

Comment: I don't mean what command you ran - I meant the command that make was running

Comment: I have no idea, how can I find that out?

Comment: It'll be on the screen, right before where all the errors are

Comment: `SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c)`. Always a bad idea to blindly grab all source
files that happen to exist. Specify the the sources of your program by name in your makefile.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: `SOURCES := foo.c bar.c gum.c # etc...`

Comment: Now it gives me:
    make:*** No rule to make target 'obj/ag.o', needed by 'program'. Stop.

Answer (score 2):

Your Makefile looks fine - I can't see any problems with it as such[*]. The problem is your code that you're compiling.

Take a look at one of the errors you're getting:

> obj/src/sv.o: In function `main':
>
> sv.c:(.text+0xcb5): multiple definition of `main'
>
> obj/src/ag.o:ag.c:(.text+0x6ef): first defined here

That is saying that you have a file called "sv.c" that has a function called `main` in it. And that you have another file called "ag.c" that also has a function called `main` in it. You're trying to compile both those files into the same program, but you're only allowed to have one function called `main`.

[*] At a guess it looks like you've got several programs living in your "src" directory and your Makefile is trying to build everything into one giant program. If this is the case you need to either separate the code into their own directories or change your Makefile so that `SOURCES` only lists the source files that are relevant to the program you're compiling.

If you want to compile several programs within the same Makefile you need to split things up. Each program needs its own build rule that specifies the dependencies it needs. You can generate the `OBJECTS` variable for each of them the same way - but you'll need to list the C files each program needs.

```
SOURCES1 = ag.c other.c something.c
SOURCES2 = sv.c morecode.c something.c

OBJECTS1 = $(foreach o, $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES1)), $(ODIR)/$o)
OBJECTS2 = $(foreach o, $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES2)), $(ODIR)/$o)

$(ODIR)/%.o : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< 

program1: $(OBJECTS1)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

program2: $(OBJECTS2)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

For reference `$^` means all the dependencies.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have a main in each program. Thank you!

Yes, I have four programs. So what changes could i make to the makefile ?
All of them are relevant since they should come togehter as a sales management system

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate who to expand the Makefile you've already got to build 2 programs - just expand it as required to cover as many programs as you need